# Having issues with installing detectron2 on windows 11

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, detectron, layout-parser

I am having some issues with installing detectron2 in Windows11.

```
!pip install -U layoutparser
!pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.4#egg=detectron2'
!pip install layoutparser[ocr]
!git clone https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser.git
model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config', 
                                 extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.8],
                                 label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"})
```

I tried these commands and tried to run the layout parser it returned

```
ImportError: 
Detectron2LayoutModel requires the detectron2 library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page: https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/INSTALL.md and follow the ones
that match your environment. Typically the following would work for MacOS or Linux CPU machines:
    pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.4#egg=detectron2'
```

Then I tried detectron for windows by following these commands

```
git clone https://github.com/DGMaxime/detectron2-windows.git
cd detectron2-windows
pip install -e
```

I received this message

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Usage:   
  C:\Users\msubh\anaconda3\envs\expOPlay\python.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Users\msubh\anaconda3\envs\expOPlay\python.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Users\msubh\anaconda3\envs\expOPlay\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  C:\Users\msubh\anaconda3\envs\expOPlay\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  C:\Users\msubh\anaconda3\envs\expOPlay\python.exe -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

-e option requires 1 argument
```

and when I tried to run layoutparser model it is saying library not found in your environment error.
Now I created new environment and ran pip install torch
I received

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
gdown 4.7.1 requires requests[socks], which is not installed.
gdown 4.7.1 requires tqdm, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires bagit>=1.7.0, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires click>=7, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires Flask, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires pyyaml, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires requests, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires sparklines>=0.4.2, which is not installed.
```

now I tried

```
pip install requests
```

```
I received 
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
bagit-profile 1.3.1 requires bagit, which is not installed.
gdown 4.7.1 requires tqdm, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires bagit>=1.7.0, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires click>=7, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires Flask, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires pyyaml, which is not installed.
ocrd 2.53.0 requires sparklines>=0.4.2, which is not installed.
ocrd-network 2.53.0 requires fastapi>=0.78.0, which is not installed.
ocrd-network 2.53.0 requires httpx>=0.22.0, which is not installed.
ocrd-network 2.53.0 requires pika>=1.2.0, which is not installed.
ocrd-network 2.53.0 requires uvicorn>=0.17.6, which is not installed.
ocrd-validators 2.53.0 requires bagit>=1.7.0, which is not installed.
ocrd-validators 2.53.0 requires click>=7, which is not installed.
ocrd-validators 2.53.0 requires pyyaml, which is not installed.
ocrd-validators 2.53.0 requires shapely, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires absl-py>=0.4, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires google-auth<3,>=1.6.3, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires grpcio>=1.48.2, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires markdown>=2.6.8, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires numpy>=1.12.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires protobuf>=3.19.6, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.13.0 requires werkzeug>=1.0.1, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires absl-py>=1.0.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires flatbuffers>=23.1.21, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires libclang>=13.0.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires numpy<=1.24.3,>=1.22, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires opt-einsum>=2.3.2, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.14,>=2.13.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1; platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin", which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires termcolor>=1.1.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires wrapt>=1.11.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.13.0 requires typing-extensions<4.6.0,>=3.6.6, but you have typing-extensions 4.7.1 which is incompatible.
```

What should I do to solve these errors and make the layout parser work

I tried to create a new environment and repeated it again. It isn't yielding any results. I will be available if you guys need any additional information from my side.